# Drawing a large number of lines (CGContextBeginPath) on an iPad

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, core-graphics, subview, drawrect

I'm trying to make an ipad application that draws alot, but I really mean alot of lines on stage (10.000+)

using this simple forloop, my ipad crashes after 40~60 seconds (without showing result)

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 10000; i++ )
    {
        int r_x = rand() % 750;
        int r_y = rand() % 1000;
        CGPoint pointpoint = CGPointMake(r_x, r_y);
        UIColor *st = [[GetColor alloc] getPixelColorAtLocation:pointpoint];
        DrawLine *drawview = [[DrawLine alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(r_x, r_y, 20, 20) selectedcolor:st];
        [self.view addSubview:drawview];
        [drawview release];
        [DrawLine release];
        [GetColor release];
    }
```

and this is my "DrawLine" class:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame selectedcolor:colors{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        selectedcolor_t = colors;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    } 
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)frame{
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    float* colors = CGColorGetComponents(selectedcolor_t.CGColor);
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, colors);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 20.0f, 20.0f);
    CGContextStrokePath(c);

}
```

how can I solve this problem? How can I draw this much subviews without crashing the iOS?

thanks so much!! :)

Comment: Dont use multiple subviews, just use one. 
At least, that is what I would do...

Comment: Well, you are trying to create 10,000 UIViews in memory. It's bound to run out. You should try drawing all those lines in a single subview as Richard says.

Comment: Richard, make your comment an answer, and we'll vote you up. :-)

Comment: It's unrelated to your problem, but I don't know what this `[[GetColor alloc] getPixelColorAtLocation:pointpoint]` is about. `alloc` messages should pretty much always be followed by some kind of `init`.

Comment: thanks for the comments :)
the getpixelcoloratlocation is a class that checks for RGB values of a seperate image, it's a messy (and very long) class so I was to ashamed to post it here, daniel's respons helped me out of the misery, back to happy coding! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please reconsider what you are doing there:

1. In line 4 of your loop, you `alloc` an instance of `GetColor` — which you never use again. Ask yourself: Does that make any sense from a design point of view?
2. In that same line, if you don't violate Cocoa's naming-conventions, you create a UIColor that is never released...
3. Then in line 8 you *release the class-object* of `DrawLine` (ditto that for the next line and the `GetColor`-class). **This is terribly, horribly wrong!**

Please visit the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) at the iOS Dev-Center and read the first two sections (again)!

Besides that, re-evaluate your design:

- Should `GetColor` really be a class, so that you create instances? Wouldn't a simple helper-function for color interpolation make more sense in this context?
- If it should be a class, why not create just one instance of it *outside of the loop* and simply query it repeatedly for the colors?
- Do you really need a subclass of UIView to draw a single straight, solid, single-colored line? If the lines need not be updated, you should (as Richard and nacho4d suggested) draw all of them in one object (e.g. by a custom UIView or by a delegate of CALayer implementing the `drawLayer:inContext:` method). If you need to update those lines later, you could simply (ab)use CALayer...

In the latter case, your problem then becomes:

1. Calculate your random coordinates.
2. Calculate your color.
3. Create an *opaque* CALayer with
   a) that color as its backgroundColor,
   b) a width of 20 * sqrt(2),
   c) a height of whatever-you-want-to-be-the-width-of-that-line,
   d) your point as its origin and
   e) a `rotation` of 45.
4. Add that layer as a sublayer to `self.view`'s layer.

Cheers
Daniel

Comment: Hey Daniel, thank you so much for your answer! :) This actually helps me alot, coming from java background I tend to mess things up, badly :p in respons to your remarks: the GetColor is a class that checks for colors on a given coordinate on an image and returns a uicolor value, I will try to implement in as a function, thanks for the tip! 
I will try to seperate the for loop and the color loop and you're a lifesaver for the CALayer tip, really improves performance!!

Comment: Ah okay, couldn't infer that from your class name. In that case, go ahead and use an object to encapsulate your image (the helper-function would have been appropriate if you were calculating something like 2d-gradient) — just don't keep recreating essentially the same thing over and over inside of your loop. Please consider using a single UIView like Richard and nacho4d suggest as well: I wasn't sure wether you needed a means to "easily" reposition the lines afterwards but assumed so.

Comment: Why would you even do something as heavyweight as create all of those layers? Maybe if this program needed to *animate* all of those lines flying around, but there's no evidence from the question that that's the case. Given that, just draw them with Core Graphics.

Comment: You're right: there's no evidence for that. I've edited my answer to include (an extended version of) the last sentence of my comment above, before I mention the CALayer option. I hope it's better now.

Answer (score 2):

If your lines are static (not moving later, not animating, etc) , as they seem to be, you could also draw all the lines in a single drawRect: in one view without creating 1000 of CALayers.
I can't tell if this is faster than drawing 1000 CALayers (because CoreAnimation is hardware accelerated and CoreGraphics is not) but it's surely lighter since all the lines will be flattened in a single *bitmap*. (which is the context of your view)

Just move your for loop inside your drawRect: and follow danyowde advices.( you just need one color object or a helper function but not to create a color each iteration)

Good luck, Hope it helps;)